# How to create docker container with Python and Orange

Tags: python, docker

Does anyone know how I create a docker container with Python and Orange, without installing the whole Anaconda package.

I managed to make it work with a container of 8.0 GB, but that is way too big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/biolab/orange3), look at the `README`, and download the appropriate `requirements-*` files. Create a directory containing the file(s), and write a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install PyQt5
COPY requirements-core.txt /tmp
RUN pip install -r requirements-core.txt
# repeat the previous two commands with other files, if needed
pip install git+https://github.com/biolab/orange3
```

Add any other commands as needed, e.g. to `COPY` your source code.